# SQL statement - NullPointerException

Tags: java, sql

I have been assigned a task at work but i'm a beginner in Java and Eclipse.
I have to re-use an existing programm and modify some parts of it.
The following part does'nt work:

```
private java.sql.Connection conn;
private final String sqlRequest = "select ... from ...";
//................

private void DBConnect(){
    try {

        // Load the driver
        java.lang.Class.forName(jdbcdriver).newInstance();
        // Connect to database
        conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL,dbuser,dbpwd);
        //................

private void search2() {   
    try     {

        // create SQL statement

        java.sql.Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();       //my line 135
        java.sql.ResultSet rs = execRequest(stmt,sqlRequest);    
        //................
```

The error message in eclipse is :

```
"java.lang.NullPointerException at mon_prog.search2(mon_prog.java:135)"
```

This part used to work before... so is the problem due to my JDK version? I have JDK7u2

Comment: Did you called the DBConnect() before search2()??

Comment: If the top exception line is 135 then `conn` is `null`.  I'm pretty sure that `getConnection` never returns null so either you did not call `DBConnect` or it threw an exception that was lost.  Check you exception logs.

Answer (score 0):

Get the connection first ...using..

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connection string);
```

Your `conn` seems null.

Comment: yes sorry i also have this method to connect to the database:

private void DBConnect(){
  try {
// Load the driver   java.lang.Class.forName(jdbcdriver).newInstance();
   
// Connect to database
conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL,dbuser,dbpwd);

...

Comment: @VincentCharrié: Please add that to your question. Also, whats der on your line 135 of mon_prog.java ??

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into great Vogella tutorial on how to connect to MySQL database from java program (IDE neutral way): http://www.vogella.de/articles/MySQLJava/article.html

Example steps to connect to your database:

```
            // This will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            // Setup the connection with the DB
            connect = DriverManager
                    .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/feedback?"
                            + "user=sqluser&password=sqluserpw");

            // Statements allow to issue SQL queries to the database
            statement = connect.createStatement();
            // Result set get the result of the SQL query
            resultSet = statement
                    .executeQuery("select * from FEEDBACK.COMMENTS");
```

Answer (score 0):

Set breakpoints on the `Class.forName()` and `getConnection()` calls in `DBConnect()`, and on your line 135, then run it all through the debugger. I wouldn't be the least bit surprised if getConnection() doesn't get executed before you try to use the connection. (Been there, done that, got the source control commit.)

If that's not it, you may also want to double-check that you really don't have another variable that is shadowing your intended `conn` instance. "Go to definition" is very useful for this; just make sure you end up in the expected place.